# How to display relational tables

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment I am creating a Membership Site. 
When a member login to the site:

```
Account Number:
Password:
```

Automatically the account of the member will display. I am currently on this but I have a problem. I am trying to connect to 2 tables on the same instance of MySQL from 1 PHP script. This table is relational in one database.

Any other ideas?

Comment: what do you need exactly? do you want to bring the data from two separate tables? for the same use? if so then you can use http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/

Comment: Are you asking the SQL or PHP code to achieve this? 
What do you want to display like what?
What is the schema of the 2 tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables are in one and the same database then simply use [JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html) operator.

If the tables are in different databases then you can do:

```
SELECT t1.fieldname1, t2.fieldname2
FROM `database1`.`table1` t1
JOIN `database2`.`table2` t2 on (...)
WHERE ...
```

Of course you have to had corresponding access rights, for the databases and the tables.

Comment: so where should I put the Join operator on my login page or to members page?